# Random Stone Brick Replacement with Worldedit in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

How does one randomly pattern mossy and cracked stone brick among regular smooth stone brick using worldedit? Is there a script for it or does the "vanilla" worldedit have the capabilities of doing that?

I'm trying to create some stronghold-esque ruins and regular smooth stone doesn't have the right atmosphere, but I don't have the time to insert cracked and mossy one by one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### You can do this using [block probability patterns](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/general/patterns/#random-pattern).

Most places you'd normally enter a single block type in WorldEdit, you can instead enter one of these which will give you a random distribution of blocks instead of just one kind. You can specify *which* blocks and how often they should show up.

As an example, if you were to select a zone and enter the following command you'd end up with something like the following screenshot:

> //replace grass,dirt **50%cloth:red,50%cloth:white**

[image: Pattern distribution example]

*Note that you cannot specify a probability pattern for the blocks you are going to replace - only for what you will replace them with.*

#### So to get dungeony walls...

Assuming you already have the stone brick walls laid out, you just want a brush that replaces some of the stone bricks with mossy or cracked stone bricks. The below commands will give you a brush with a radius of 5 that exclusively targets stone brick (all kinds, including mossy and cracked) and replaces it with 70% regular stone brick (`stonebrick:0`), 10% mossy stone brick (`stonebrick:1`) and 20% cracked stone brick (`stonebrick:2`).

> /brush sphere **70%stonebrick:0,10%stonebrick:1,20%stonebrick:2** 5
>
> /mask stonebrick

Just tweak the probabilities until you get an effect you like. You might want to make certain areas more mossy, or certain areas less mossy and more cracked, so play with it a bit.

Further documentation on commands used here:

- [Utility commands](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/commands/#utility-commands) describes `//replace`
- [Brush commands](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/commands/#brush-commands) describes `/brush`
- [Tool commands](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/commands/#tool-commands) describes `/mask`

Comment: This wasn't working for me when I tried it before, as my worldedit was outdated, but it works perfectly with the latest version. Thanks.

Comment: The "block probability patterns" link appears to be dead.

Comment: @EJMak Thank you! Looks like WorldEdit switched its documentation platform. :) I've updated the post.

Answer (score -2):

//replace grass,dirt 50%cloth:red,50%cloth:white for example like above, or //replace grass,dirt 50%4,50%1

Comment: Care to add an explanation as to how this solves the asker's problem?  I'm not really seeing it.